# Sql trigger to make another column required with specific details after inserting information in another column on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am new to SQL and programming generally and i have been struggling with a few things and i need help desperately.
 i  am creating a table : "Transactions.Revenue"

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions.Revenue (
    PaymentID int identity (101,1) Not Null Constraint Pk_Payment_ID Primary Key,
    MemberID int Identity(001,1) Not Null Constraint Fk_Member_ID Foreign Key references Member.MemberDetails (MemberID),
    PaymentDate datetime,
    Payment_Method Varchar (15) Not Null Constraint Ch_Payment_Method check (Payment_Method in ('Cash','Cheque','Credit_Card')),
    CC_Name Varchar (30), 
    CC_Num varchar (20),
    Cheque_Num varchar (20),
    PaymentStatus Varchar (10) Not Null Constraint Ch_Payment_Status Check (PaymentStatus in ('Paid','Pending'))
)
```

1.`CC_Name` and `CC_Num` should record credit card number and credit card name if payment is made using credit card if not fields should be left blank.

2.`Cheque_Num` should record cheque number if payment is made using cheque, if not, field should be left blank.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What is your question?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using SQL Management studio 2008 My question is how do i write the trigger to make --CC_Name and CC_Num  record credit card number and credit card name if payment is made using credit card if not fields should be left blank....  and also

2.Cheque_Num  record cheque number if payment is made using cheque, if not, field should be left blank.... ...

Comment: @Blitz . . . Sample data and desired results would make the question clearer.

Comment: Sounds like you need a couple more check constraints, not a trigger (unless this is some form of assignment where a trigger is a mandatory part of the solution, in which case you ought to at least disclose that fact and include your attempt to solve it yourself)

Comment: thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever, no it's not an assignment. i was reading and attempted to do it myself before looking up the solution.and when i read about triggers, i assumed that would be the solution to it. but i haven't used them before.

Comment: You can't have two identity fields in the same table. The FK should not be an identity.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you would do in a trigger.  You do this in the front end code where you create your INSERT statements.

What you can do with either a trigger or better yet, a CHECK CONSTRAINT, is enforce a rule like "IF Payment_Method='Cheque' THEN Check_Number must not be NULL".

If you do this in a Trigger, then you would have to write code to raise an error when this situation occurs.   If you use a constraint, an error will automatically be raised if a row violates the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a couple more check constraints - but as table constraints rather than column constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions.Revenue (
    PaymentID int identity (101,1) Not Null Constraint Pk_Payment_ID Primary Key,
    MemberID int Not Null Constraint Fk_Member_ID Foreign Key
                           references Member.MemberDetails (MemberID),
    PaymentDate datetime,
    Payment_Method Varchar (15) Not Null Constraint Ch_Payment_Method check 
             (Payment_Method in ('Cash','Cheque','Credit_Card')),
    CC_Name Varchar (30), 
    CC_Num varchar (20),
    Cheque_Num varchar (20),
    PaymentStatus Varchar (10) Not Null Constraint Ch_Payment_Status Check 
             (PaymentStatus in ('Paid','Pending')),
    constraint CK_PaymentMethodMatchCC CHECK (
       (CC_Name is null and CC_Num is null and Payment_Method != 'Credit_Card') or
       (CC_Name is not null and CC_Num is not null and Payment_Method = 'Credit_Card')
    ),
    constraint CK_PaymentMethodMatchChq CHECK (
       (Cheque_Num is null and Payment_Method != 'Cheque') or
       (Cheque_Num is not null and Payment_Method = 'Cheque')
    )
)
```